# visualization idea on a panel data (roughly speaking)

Tags: pandas, visualization

I wanted to construct a heat map on the following data:

```
variable    bins    2000    2001    2004
    0       binA    2282447 2228013 2024397
    1       binB    264863  279788  355826
    2       binC    290533  304756  372788
    3       binD    211721  222480  257667
    4       binE    134966  142113  156282
```

Ideally I want (bins, bins) in a scatter plot or a heatmap. This is time series so to speak panel data (roughly saying). Any visualization idea on this?